# ¿Como guardar un carrito de compra en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, gson

estoy diseñando un carrito de compras en android, y quisiera saber como guardar los datos que este almacena. o qué ideas pueden darme para guardar estos datos en una base de datos. Ya que si solo guardo las variables solo ingresa el último elemento de que se muestra
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
public class Cesta extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Elemento> cesta = new ArrayList<>();
    SharedPreferences carrito;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    TextView mos;
     Button btnOrdenar;
    double total =0;
    int cant=0;
    String producto;
    double montobd=0;
    double precio=0;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cesta);

        carrito=getSharedPreferences("carrito",MODE_PRIVATE);
        String guardado = carrito.getString("cesta","");

        ////gson convierte el elemento guardado a un arraylist
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Elemento>>(){}.getType();
        cesta=gson.fromJson(guardado,type);

        btnOrdenar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOrdenar);
        btnOrdenar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(total==0|producto==""|montobd==0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El carrito está vacío ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Compras.class);
                    i.putExtra("total",total);
                    i.putExtra("cantidad",cant);
                    i.putExtra("monto",montobd);
                    i.putExtra("nombre",producto);

                    startActivity(i);
                }





        }
        });
        cuerpoCesta();


    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    public void cuerpoCesta(){
        final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llCesta);
        ll.removeAllViews();
        LinearLayout linearLayout=null;
        CardView cardView=null;

        DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
        total=0;
        cant = 0;
        montobd = 0;
        precio=0;
        for (int i=0;i<cesta.size();i++){
            Elemento E= cesta.get(i);
            cardView = new CardView(ll.getContext());
            linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            linearLayout.setOrientation((LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL));
            linearLayout.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
            cardView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
            cardView.setContentPadding(10,10,10,10);
            cardView.setCardElevation(10);

            final TextView txtPro=new TextView(this);
            txtPro.setText(E.getNombre());
            txtPro.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(450, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


            final TextView txtPre=new TextView(this);
            txtPre.setText("$"+E.getPrecio()+"");
            txtPre.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(330, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            final TextView txtCan=new TextView(this);
            txtCan.setText(E.getCantidad()+"");
            txtCan.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            final TextView txtMonto=new TextView(this);
            double montoCompra=E.getPrecio()*E.getCantidad();

            formato.format(montoCompra);
            txtMonto.setText("$"+montoCompra+"");
            txtMonto.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            final Button btnRestar= new Button(this);
            btnRestar.setText("X");

            btnRestar.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            final String cod=cesta.get(i).getCodigo();
            btnRestar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    for (int i=0; i<cesta.size();i++){
                        if (cesta.get(i).getCodigo().equalsIgnoreCase(cod)){
                            cesta.get(i).setCantidad(cesta.get(i).getCantidad()-1);
                            if (cesta.get(i).getCantidad()<1)
                                cesta.remove(i);
                        }
                    }
                    String jsonList = gson.toJson(cesta);
                    carrito = getSharedPreferences("carrito",MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = carrito.edit();
                    editor.putString("cesta",jsonList);
                    //commin es guardar datos y cerrar preferencias
                    editor.commit();
                    cuerpoCesta();
                }
            });

            linearLayout.addView(txtPro);
            linearLayout.addView(txtPre);
            linearLayout.addView(txtCan);
            linearLayout.addView(txtMonto);
            linearLayout.addView(btnRestar);
            cardView.addView(linearLayout);

            ll.addView(cardView);

            formato.format(total+=montoCompra);
            cant=E.getCantidad();
            producto = E.getNombre();
            montobd = montoCompra;
            precio = E.getPrecio();




        }

        final TextView txtTextoTotal = new TextView(this);
        txtTextoTotal.setText("Total a apagar");
        txtTextoTotal.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(800, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            txtTextoTotal.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_END);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            txtTextoTotal.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_GRAVITY);
        }

        final TextView txtTotal = new TextView(this);

        txtTotal.setText(formato.format(total));
        txtTotal.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(280, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            txtTotal.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_END);
        }



        LinearLayout linearLayout2 = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        linearLayout2.addView(txtTextoTotal);
        linearLayout2.addView(txtTotal);

        ll.addView(linearLayout2);

    }




    }
```

Answer (score 2):

la mejor forma de crear carritos de compra es con una base de datos local, así cuando agregas al carrito el item , lo guardas en la base de datos , y al final lo puedes mostrar en la tabla . Esto te permite persistir los datos aunque te salgas de la app. Yo he usado SQLLite para crear una . [Te envio un tutorial de como usarlo.](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-sqlite-bases-de-datos/)

También puedes usar SharedPreferences esto te permite crear archivos en la app , aunque la cierres, pero no es recomendable guardar mucho ahí.